# Identity of Ring with Euclidean Norm

Tags: ring-theory

let $A$ be a ring that is commutative and also has a euclidean norm function  $d$. Then $A$ must have an multiplicative identity.

Here $d$ is a function from nonzero elements of $A$ to non-negative integers satisfying the property: for every $a$ and nonzero $b$ in A there exists $q$ and $r$ in $A$ such that $a=bq+r$ and either  $r=0$ or $d(r)<d(b)$.

Comment: I think the only assumption is that the ring is commutative and has a norm that acts like a Euclidean norm.

Comment: exactly as you are thinking @pval

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Let $a=b\ne0$,  show $q$ the quotient constructed satisfies the property of an identity.

EDIT: You likely want to assume $N(x)>0$ for all $x>0$ or the following is a counter example: $$k\times 2\Bbb Z$$ under the norm $N(x,0)=1$ for nonzero $x$ , $N(x,y)=0$ for nonzero $y$. This is multiplicative and satisfies the euclidean property. ($k$ is just an arbitrary field)

Comment: how do you know that the quotient q is unique or independent of choice of a?

Comment: The identity property actually forces it to be unique. Consider the product of two identities $e_1e_2=e_2$ and $e_1e_2=e_1$ since $e_1$ and $e_2$ are identity elements. So $e_1=e_2$.

Comment: @PVAL: That's not actually enough. You don't get that $e_1$ is a multiplicative identity- instead, you're given that it's an element of norm 1 which happens to satisfy $ae_1=a$. Some more work (or explanation, in case I've missed something) needs to happen.

Comment: @KReiser All I'm showing is uniqueness of an identity in my comment so if $q$ satisfies the identity properties it is unique.

Comment: @PVAL: Okay, great. I agree that you've shown that if there exists a multiplicative identity in a commutative ring, it's unique. I don't think you've shown that the $q$ you pick up from running the norm property on $a$ and $a$ satisfies the identity properties- there's more work to be done here. For example, suppose $q$ is a non-identity non-zero idempotent, and $a\in qA$. How does one exclude this case?

Comment: @KReiser If $A$ has no zero divisors you are done as the cancellation law does not require an identity. Most euclidean norms assume $N(x)>0$ for all $x\ne 0$ if you do not assume this there is a counter example which I will include in my post shortly